# Javascript object callback not being called on webkit

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I have defined a js "class" like this:

```
var TelephoneFormGroup = function(targetId, removePhoneCallback) {

    this.phone = '';
    this.phone_type_options = [];
    this.counter = 0;
    this.targetId = targetId;
    this.form_group = {};
    this.removePhone = removePhoneCallback;

    this.buildFormGroup = function() {
        var outerDiv = document.createElement('div');
        outerDiv.className = 'form-group';

        var label = document.createElement('label');
        label.className = 'label-control col-sm-3';

        var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
        innerDiv.className = 'col-sm-8';

        var inputId = document.createElement('input');
        inputId.type = 'hidden';
        inputId.name = 'data[Telephone][' + this.counter + '][id]';

        var inputPhoneTypeId = document.createElement('select');
        inputPhoneTypeId.name = 'data[Telephone][' + this.counter + '][phone_type_id]';
        inputPhoneTypeId.className = 'form-control col-sm-3';

        var removePhoneIcon = document.createElement('i');
        removePhoneIcon.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove";

        var removePhoneLink = document.createElement('a');
        removePhoneLink.appendChild(removePhoneIcon);
        removePhoneLink.title = "Remover Telefone";
        removePhoneLink.href = "#";
        removePhoneLink.dataset.toggle = "tooltip";

        removePhoneLink.onclick = this.removePhone;

        label.appendChild(removePhoneLink);
        label.innerHTML += 'Telefone ' + this.counter;

        var that = this;
        Object.keys(this.phone_type_options).forEach( function(key) {
            inputPhoneTypeId.options[inputPhoneTypeId.options.length] = new Option(that.phone_type_options[key], key);
        });

        var inputPhone = document.createElement('input');
        inputPhone.type = 'text';
        inputPhone.name = 'data[Telephone][' + this.counter + '][phone]';
        inputPhone.className = 'form-control phone col-sm-9';


        outerDiv.appendChild(label);
        outerDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
        innerDiv.appendChild(inputId);
        innerDiv.appendChild(inputPhoneTypeId);
        innerDiv.appendChild(inputPhone);

        this.form_group = outerDiv;
    },

    this.render = function() {
        if (this.targetId == null || this.targetId == '') throw 'Empty target id';

        if (typeof(this.targetId) === 'string') {
            document.getElementById(this.targetId).appendChild(this.form_group);    
        } else if (typeof(this.targetId === 'object')) {
            this.targetId.appendChild(this.form_group);
        };

    }

};
```

My issue is that `removePhoneLink.onclick = this.removePhone;` is not firing on webkit browsers. Works correctly on Firefox (mac), but its not working on safari/chrome (mac), safari/chrome (ipad).

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** attach the element to the DOM before attaching the event handler

Thanks for the interesting case. After a few tries, I figured WebKit needs the element attached to the DOM before registering the event handler (stumbled accross [Todd Motto's example](https://toddmotto.com/attaching-event-handlers-to-dynamically-created-javascript-elements/), he does get the element with jQuery before attaching the event handler!)

Here's [a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/naxs6Le3/) of your code, annotated.
Mainly, I added a bindEventHandlers method called after the render method, made the whole object into a fluent interface with chained method (a la jQuery), added a static counter on the "class".
Short excerpts :

- keep track of how many objects were instantiated

  ```
  TelephoneFormGroup.counter = ++TelephoneFormGroup.counter || 0;
  this.counter = TelephoneFormGroup.counter;
  ```
- encapsulate the callback in a method and call it with `apply` (ensures the method is called on the right object, had some problem with this on another project)

  ```
  this.removePhone = function(){
      removePhoneCallback.apply(this);
  };
  ```
- bound `this` to your `Object.keys`'s `forEach` (removed `var that=this;` trick)

  ```
  Object.keys(this.phone_type_options).forEach( function(key) {
      inputPhoneTypeId.options[inputPhoneTypeId.options.length] = new Option(this.phone_type_options[key], key);
  }.bind(this));
  // Here, we tell forEach we want 'this' to be bound to the object, not the current item being iterated over (i.e. that=this trick)
  ```
- since the `removePhoneLink` construction is now built in two phase (build markup, then attach event handlers), we couple it using a dynamically created id

  ```
  ...
  // in buildFormGroup()
  removePhoneLink.id = "btnRemove"+this.targetId;
  ...

  // called after attaching the form group to the dom
  this.bindEventHandlers = function() {
      document.getElementById("btnRemove"+this.targetId).onclick = function(e) {
          this.removePhone();
      }.bind(this);
  }
  ```

I hope it works for your use case. I tried it on Chrome and Safari (Mac OS X Yosemite).

**edit :** I found your code interesting, simple, yet complicated enough for a small test I had in mind for a while. All your methods are bound to the instantiated object. With JavaScript and the prototype pattern, you should add methods to the object's prototype (as in [this fiddle for your code](https://jsfiddle.net/s9x5fpav/2/)).
I did a small benchmark to compare the two techniques, checking memory usage and time to complete the method ([machine spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115145/javascript-object-callback-not-being-called-on-webkit/35117747#35117747)).
I would use Chrome Developer tools (heap size runs, refresh between runs, then render time runs, refresh between runs).
Find [the results there (fiddle.md)](https://fiddle.md/nc2s22fpkr8b7kdv47nv25).
As you can see, it doesn't yield much difference until 50 objects are instantiated. Then you'd render until 18% faster with prototypes, and gain up to almost 30% in memory usage (for the 50'000 objects run).
So I guess for a production use, go for prototypes?

Comment: Hey, this is awesome! I just noticed I wrote this class as I would write a C# class and totally forgot about prototypes. Binding the event before adding it to the DOM is what was causing the issue on webkit browsers and I really appreciate you taking your time to help me out. I'll switch to using prototypes as well. +1 for benchmark results on both techniques.